# On-prem to cloud vulnerability scanning

Tags: security, cloud, penetration-testing, penetration-tools, crlf-vulnerability

We have vulnerability scanning software in a shared subnet our on-prem network.  We are now adding VMs hosted on the public cloud and need to perform vulnerability scanning on them.  One option is to open one-way traffic from on-prem to public cloud so that the scanner can reach all VMs. So all ports will be open to VMs (in one direction). Is this desirable? Would it not be better to run vul scan software within the subnets so that no traffic needs to be allowed at all between on-prem and cloud? The scanner running in the same subnet as VMs could push results to the central scanner server in a dmz for example.  How do companies adapting public cloud solve this?

Comment: Not sure if this belongs on [sf] or [networkengineering.se] or even [security.se], but it is certainly not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's becoming more common to leverage existing scanner software in the cloud. On platforms like AWS, many commercial products will also have an AMI for this purpose. For example: https://community.tenable.com/s/article/Amazon-Machine-Image-Deployment-AMI

The real answer here depends on some of the following:

- The cloud platform you use.
- The vulnerability scanning software you need to use.
- The services you use within the cloud.

It's also worth considering adopting a product or toolset that can integrate with your cloud environment to scan new assets as they are created. If your cloud stack use non-VM services (like AWS S3) require their own very specific types of scanning as well.